# Is it possible to define const value and than ask from the user to enter it?

Tags: c, macros, scanf, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to define a const value in C:

```
#define N;
```

and than ask from the user to enter is using scanf()?

If so, How?

Comment: What do you mean by "const value"?  Do you really mean only a `#define` constant per your example?  Do you mean any compile-time constant?  Or will a `const` value (i.e., a variable qualified with the `const` keyword) do?  If so, then: `const int N = get_user_input();`. (Be aware that `const`-qualified variables aren't compile-time constants in C, however.)

Answer (score 3):

`#define`ed values are not normal const. They are calculated / converted by the preprocessor, so you lose them at compile time, and surely can't change them at runtime.

Note that the syntax for such a `#define` is `#define N  5` rather than `#define N;`

Answer (score 2):

The expansion of a preprocessor macro definition is set when the preprocessing phase runs, which is even before the bulk of compilation.

So for example, if you do `#define N 5`, then `N` will always be `5`, never anything else.

If you do `#define N my_global_integer`, then `N` will always be `my_global_integer`, never anything else.

So I suppose you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N my_global_integer
int my_global_integer;

int main() {
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("%d\n", N);
}
```

The preprocessor macro `N` is constant, but the variable that it ends up expanding to is not. I wouldn't normally advise it, but if this question were a puzzle then that might be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Things that you define using `define` are replaced textually by the pre-processor before the actual compiler even sees the source code.

Besides, constants shouldn't change, that should be pretty obvious red flag regarding your idea.

Answer (score 0):

No, because `#define`s are inserted into the code at compile-time using a [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). They cannot be changed at runtime.